# cucumber, rspec and rails 3 raises error option: --profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I used cucumber for the first time with rails 3.

Gemfile

```
group :test do
 gem "rspec"
 gem "rspec-rails"
 gem "database_cleaner"
 gem "spork"
 gem "cucumber",         :git => "git://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber.git"
 gem "cucumber-rails",   :git => "git://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber-rails.git"
 gem "capybara"
 gem "capybara-envjs"
 gem "launchy"
 gem "ruby-debug"
end
```

and used the generator to install the cucumber skeleton

```
rails generate cucumber:install --rspec --capybara
```

this generates a cucumber.yml

```
<%
rerun = File.file?('rerun.txt') ? IO.read('rerun.txt') : ""
rerun_opts = rerun.to_s.strip.empty? ? "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'progress'} features" : "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} #{rerun}"
std_opts = "--format #{ENV['CUCUMBER_FORMAT'] || 'pretty'} --strict --tags ~@wip"
%>
default: <%= std_opts %> features
wip: --tags @wip:3 --wip features
rerun: <%= rerun_opts %> --format rerun --out rerun.txt --strict --tags ~@wip
```

if I run the simplest feature it runs through but after the test it raises an exception

```
$ rake cucumber
bundle exec /Users/www/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/bin/ruby -I "/Users/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@my_app/bundler/gems/cucumber-e2df150cc4fd/lib:lib" "/Users/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@my_app/bundler/gems/cucumber-e2df150cc4fd/bin/cucumber"  --profile default
Using the default profile...
(...)
1 scenario (1 passed)
2 steps (2 passed)
0m0.146s
invalid option: --profile
Test::Unit automatic runner.
Usage: /Users/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@my_app/bundler/gems/cucumber-e2df150cc4fd/bin/cucumber [options] [-- untouched arguments]
```

I can't find the solution for this little problem, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `cucumber features` or simply `cucumber` instead of `rake cucumber`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with putting this file **features/support/minitest_disable.rb** the following code:

```
require 'multi_test'
MultiTest.disable_autorun
```

and see this [discussion](https://github.com/cucumber/multi_test/pull/2#issuecomment-21863459) in cucumber project